# How do I match columns in a small file to a larger file and do calculations using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have this small file *small.csv*:

```
STATE|STAGE|SUBCAT_ID|TOTAL TIMING|FAMA_COEFF_TIMING|DB_IMPORT_TIMING|COMMENT
SUCCEEDED|fe|L3-002559|110|7|15
SUCCEEDED|staging|L3-002241|46||24
```

And this bigger file *big.csv*:

```
STATE|STAGE|SUBCAT_ID|TOTAL TIMING|FAMA_COEFF_TIMING|DB_IMPORT_TIMING|COMMENT
SUCCEEDED|fe|L3-004082|16|0|8
SUCCEEDED|staging|L3-002730|85||57
SUCCEEDED|staging|L3-002722|83||56
SUCCEEDED|fe|L3-002559|100|7|15
```

I need a command (probably awk) that will loop on the small.csv file to check if the 1st, 2nd and 3rd column match a record in the big.csv file and then calculate based on the 4th column the difference small-big. So in the example above, since the 1st record's first 3 columns match the 4th record in big.csv the output would be:

```
SUCCEEDED|fe|L3-002559|10
```

where 10 is 110-100

Thank you

Comment: Please can you show us what you have tried and how it failed? Or can you at least tell us what prevented you from trying yet? (ie, what info do you need?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that lines with similar first three fields do not occur more than twice in the two files taken together. This works:

```
awk -F '|' 'FNR!=1 { key = $1 "|" $2 "|" $3; if(a[key]) print key "|" a[key]-$4; else a[key]=$4 }' small.csv big.csv
```